# Как выбрать нужное поле из базы данных?

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Логика такая:
Пользователь проходит тест на стороне клиента, в результате прохождения которого зарабатывает "score". В конце, с помощью AJAX запроса передаю в php скрипт значение "score" и название проходимого теста "name" **(данные передаются)**

На стороне php нужно совершать такие действия:

1. Загрузить данные о пользователе чья сейчас сессия
2. Проверить, есть ли уже значение "name" в связанной с user (1:M) таблицей 
   "tests"
3. Если есть, то после нескольких условий изменить данные в нескольких полях
4. Если нет, создать новую запись

Новая запись создается, но только первый раз, если ни один другой user еще не создавал ее, все остальное **не работает** **(Никаких ответов и ошибок от сервера не приходит)**

Что я написал не так?

php скрипт:

```
<?php
require "db.php";
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
  // Получаем id users чья сессия
  $userid = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;
  // Загружаем данные об этом user
  $user = R::load( 'users', $userid );

  // Дальше я не уверен в том правильно ли я сделал выборку

  // ищем запись $_POST['name'] в поле "name" в таблице "tests" 
  $findTest = R::findOne('tests', 'name = ?', array($_POST['name']));
  //Если такая запись есть
  if ($findTest) {
    //В цикле, который по идее перебирает именно данные юзера с id = $_SESSION['logged_user']
    foreach( $user->ownTestsList as $test ) {
      //Если найдено поле = $_POST['name']
      if ($test->name == $_POST['name']) {
        //При этом, если значение progress  в базе < $_POST['score']
        if ($test->progress < $_POST['score']) {
          //То записываем новое значение в progress
          $test->progress = $_POST['score'];
          //И записываем новое значение в time 
          $test->time = strtotime("now");
          //Записываем новые данные в бд к тому самому юзеру, чье id = $_SESSION['logged_user']
          $user->ownTestsList[] = $test;
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  //Если запись не найдена $findTest
  else {
    //Создаем новое поле в таблице "tests"
    $test = R::dispense('tests');
    $test->name = $_POST['name'];
    $test->progress = $_POST['score'];
    $test->time = strtotime("now");
    $user->ownTestsList[] = $test;
  }
  //Сохраняем данные
  R::store($user);
}
?>
```

Comment: Научитесь дебагать свой код.

Comment: Слишком сложная логика, нужно идти путём `от простого к сложному`. Если Ваша идея такова: `пользователь проходит тест, если он набрал больше балов чем в предыдущий раз то поставим большую оценку, если тест первый раз - создадим новую запись`, то вся логика сводится к трём простым шагам: идентификация пользователя, поиск записи о прохождении теста, ответ пользователю. + Смотрите логи своего веб-сервера.

Comment: @Владислав да именно такая логика, просто я пытался объяснить ее в контексте моего кода

Comment: @КириллМиронов И в чём возникла проблема? Какие изменения происходят в базе данных? Как самый простой пример по отладке кода `var_dump($variable)`, получим распечатку переменной.

Comment: @Владислав Т.е. по идее в скрипте все верно? Я просто хотел узнать как именно нужно искать подобные значения в бд с помощью redbeanphp. xdebug показывает, что скрипт находит нужную запись, но не для того юзера, чья сессия(id=2), а того у кого впервые появилась эта запись(id=1)

Comment: @КириллМиронов К сожалению, или к радости я не имел дело с RedBean, но предполагаю что принцип работы стандартный - использование `PDO`. По поводу Вашего скрипта: я ничего сказать не могу, переформулируйте вопрос, добавьте больше информации, хотя-бы: `var_dump($_SESSION['logged_user'])`, `var_dump($user)`, `зачем вы используете цикл foreach, если тест один, какие данные Вы пытаетесь изменить`. Я могу Вам подробно ответить, но для простоты вместо RedBean будет `Eloquent`.